# Method that Writes an array as text to file read by humans

Tags: java, file-io

I have a practice question that asks me to write a method that  receives an array of employees and a file name.  It writes the individual employee (salesman or technician) info as text to a file which can be read by humans. This is the code i have so far

```
 public static void writeAsText (employees[], String fileName)throws IOException
   {  
      // Write the text to the file
      File myFile = new File("text.dat");
      FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(myFile);
      BufferedWriter myBufferOut = new BufferedWriter(myWriter);

      //Loops through array
      for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) 
      {
        myBufferOut.write(employees[i]+"");
      }
      myBufferOut.close();  
   }
```

Pls i just need your opinion to know if i have answered the question right. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You don't give a type for your employee array.  If the type you are using implements `toString` properly, then it may work as you expect.  Otherwise, it won't.

Comment: Yes it is Java, I didnt implement the data type for my employee array because i felt it is supposed to be an array of "Objects". Employee Objects.

Comment: What I'm asking is, have you or have you not implemented a `toString` override?

Comment: Oh yes i have a toString() method in another class!

Comment: And also, I have a super.toString method in two other classes.

Comment: So... What type is the employee array?